# Doubts about SPF record missing

Tags: dns, spam-prevention, spf

I'm trying to add SPF records on my DNS zone. The SPF records are from mailjet (spf.mailjet.com), the domain is brazilian (.com.br hosted on uolhost) and my server is on DigitalOcean. When i try to add the TXT record, mailjet says "Your SPF record is missing".

I added this TXT (suggested by mailjet) on my DNS zone (at uolhost):

```
v=spf1 include:spf.mailjet.com ?all
```

But i have some questions about it (i'm really a beginner on this subjects).

- The TXT should be on digital ocean, uolhost or both?
- I really have to wait 48h?
- The TXT above is correct?

Sorry for my bad english. I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should make it `-all` instead of `~all`, the whole reason to set up authentication is to prevent people from spoofing your domain.

```
v=spf1 include:spf.mailjet.com -all
```

Where you're SPF record goes, depends on where the SPF record is being sent from, or the 5321.From Which is the "Return-Path", etc. Not the "FROM" line.

So view the headers of your email and look for the return path email address.

Whichever domain that is, is the place in DNS you will add the TXT record above, if you don't know how to see the headers of your email just send an email to `mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com` it will send you your header information on top of the report, just look for "Return-path". There is also an SPF Section, when you have it set up right it will show "PASSED".

Comment: It will help a lot. I'll test tonight. Thanks.

Comment: I am actually surprised that Mailjet, in their official documentation, have th example with ?all without mentioning the fact that the ? basically disables the record at all.

Answer (score 3):

BTW, if you have multiple SPF records (one of an email service provider and the other of mailjet); then instead of adding 2 TXT records, please use a single TXT record with a combination like below:

`v=spf1 include:spf.mailjet.com include:spf.protection.outlook.com ~all`

(since we use outlook email service, hence outlook in our case).